# Elastic Search Aggregation buckets, buckets by number of records

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search and I'm trying to create a request without a lot of success. Here is the use case:

Let's imagine I have 4 documents, which have an `amount` field:

```
[
  {
    "id": 541436748332,
    "amount": 5,
    "date": "2017-01-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 6348643512,
    "amount": 2,
    "date": "2017-03-13"
  },
  {
    "id": 343687432,
    "amount": 2,
    "date": "2017-03-14"
  },
  {
    "id": 6457866181,
    "amount": 7,
    "date": "2017-05-21"
  }
]
```

And here is the kind of result I'd like to get:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "my_aggregation": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum": 7
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum": 9
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I want some kind of histogram, but instead of putting a date interval, I'd like to set a "document" interval. So here, that would be 2 documents per bucket, and the sum of the field `amount` of those two documents.

**Does someone knows if that is even possible? That would also imply to sort the records by date for example, to get the wanted results**

EDIT: Some more explanations on the use case:

*The real use case is a line graph I'd like to print. But I want to make the X axis the number of sales, and in the Y the total amount $$$ of those sales. And I don't want to print thousands of dot on my graph, I want fewer dots, that's why I was hoping to deal with the buckets and the sums...*
The example of response I gave is just the first step I want to achieve, the second step would be to add each field the one that is behind it:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "my_aggregation": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum": 7
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 2,
          "sum": 16
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(7 = 5 + 2); (16 = 7 (from last result) + 2 + 7);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) and [sum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) aggregations, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "prices": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "id",
        "interval": 2,
        "offset": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(`offset` 1 is required if you want the first bucket to start at 1 instead of at 0.) Then you'll get a response like this:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "prices": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "total_amount": {
            "value": 7
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 3,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "total_amount": {
            "value": 9
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Sorting is not required, because the default order is the order you want. However, there's also an `order` parameter in case you want a different ordering of the buckets.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Problem is, it may happen that ids of the documents don't follow each other. And from what I understand, this would break the idea wouldn't it?

Comment: Broken how? It works for your example. :) It also works for some data I have (which has non-consecutive integer values). You can get empty buckets, obviously, but that is expected in a histogram.

Comment: Ah I see, because you want exactly 2 documents per bucket. That's not really a histogram, exactly. In that case I don't think it's possible. Maybe you can update your question to describe more of your use case (so someone might be able to suggest an alternative solution).

Comment: Also I would suggest to update your question so that the example shows this requirement (with non-consecutive ids)

Comment: Let's say the id is some random generated key, then if you make intervals of two on the ids, it won't work anymore because it has no logic in it am I wrong? Maybe it can't be achievable, I didn't see kind of that in the elasticsearch doc, maybe I'll just prepare my data with some old fashion javascript...

Comment: I edited my question with some random ID and a date to order the docs by in case someone has an other solution, thank you for your help anyway! If no one comes to answer the question today, I'll mark it as resolved...

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the use case? I am pretty sure there's not a solution directly to what you're asking, but there may be a solution to whatever you're using it for. I assume in your real case you would have more than 2 documents per bucket right?  (Otherwise you would just query the data directly, because you'd receive only 2x as much data.)

Comment: The real use case is a line graph I'd like to print. But I want to make the X axis the number of sales, and in the Y the total amount $$$ of those sales. And I don't want to print thousands of dot on my graph, I want fewer dots, that's why I was hoping to deal with the buckets and the sums...

Comment: You could add a new field (which will be consecutive integers) using this approach: http://blogs.perl.org/users/clinton_gormley/2011/10/elasticsearchsequence---a-blazing-fast-ticket-server.html (this only works if you don't delete data of course) -- it makes indexing more complex, but it's cool! :)